# RPG Dice Roller

Tags: python, beginner, random, simulation, dice

This is sort of a follow up to my post [yesterday](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15778/how-can-i-make-this-code-better).  I'm a relative newbie to Python and before I made a d20 dice roller for RPGs.  Now I've made a dice roller for any type of dice, and I would love some feedback on this code.

```
from random import randint

def roll(sides, number_of_dice):
    """Rolls Dice."""
    return [randint(1, sides) for i in range(num_of_dice)]

prompt = """
Would you like to roll the same combination of dice {}? 
Please type 'yes', 'no', or 'quit'
"""

# Main Program

name = raw_input("\nPlease tell me your name > ")

print """
Hello {} and welcome to an RPG Dice Roller by Ray Weiss.
Please type quit when prompted to exit or use CNTRL-C. 
Thanks to everyone at Stack Overflow etc. for the help. 
""".format(name)

sides = input("\nHow many sides do you want on your dice? > ")
num_of_dice = input("\nHow many {} sided dice do you want to roll? >".format(sides))
results = roll(sides, num_of_dice)
print results

roll_again = raw_input(prompt.format(name))

while True:

    if roll_again == "yes":
        results = roll(sides, num_of_dice)
        print results
        roll_again = raw_input(prompt.format(name))

    if roll_again == "no": 
        sides = input("How many sides do you want on your dice? > ")
        num_of_dice = input("\nHow many {} sided dice do you want to roll? >".format(sides))
        results = roll(sides, num_of_dice)
        print results
        roll_again = raw_input(prompt.format(name))

    if roll_again == "quit":
        print """
Thank you {} for using this RPG Dice Roller by Ray Weiss! Goodbye!
        """.format(name)
        break
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the big thing here is to **beware of external data**. Assume that it could be garbage.

For instance:

- What happens if the user doesn't enter a name? -> Actually, not much apart from 2 spaces (rather than 1) in messages - relatively benign.
- What happens if the user enters "rabbit" sides? -> This value in any case needs to be transformed to an int for `roll` to work correctly otherwise a TypeError will be thrown. `int("rabbit")` will throw a ValueError (see last item)
- Similarly, `num_of_dice` also have to be validated as a positive integer (non-zero).
- If the user enters something wrong for `roll_again` (say, "of course!"), you'll enter an infinite loop - The question probably needs to be brought inside the loop.
- You'll want to use `raw_input` rather than `input` in python2. `Input` evaluates an expression, which does what you want here (enter a number, get an int back (unless of course it's a float!)), but should be regarded as *avoid if at all possible*.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not so sure how to do many of these things as a newbie but its more for me to learn! I appreciate it!